# How to add vercel env vars from .env file

Tags: environment-variables, vercel

How can I push the contents of `.env` to vercel using the CLI?

I am aware of the `vercel add NAME VALLUE` command; which adds one env var. I did not see any way to add a whole file.

I have thought about creating a makefile that reads the `.env` file and does a for loop line by line; however this approach feels extremely finicky